# Incorrect display of django admin panel in chrome

Tags: django, django-admin

My problem is that the admin panel is not displayed correctly in the chrome browser (for example, everything is fine in yandex). Several windows seem to overlap each other and work with the panel becomes impossible. This has happened since the beginning of the project. At the same time, everything seems to be fine with the styles. I would be very grateful for any help!

URLs.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/', include('Вход.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('Главная.urls')),
    url(r'^Новости/', include('Новости.urls')),
    url(r'^Видео/', include('Видео.urls')),
    url(r'^Фото/', include('Фото.urls')),
    url(r'^Аудио/', include('Аудио.urls')),
    url(r'^Документы/', include('Документы.urls')),
    url(r'^О_нас/', include('О_нас.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() + static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Главная',
    'Вход',
    'Новости',
    'Видео',
    'Фото',
    'Аудио',
    'Документы',
    'О_нас',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Крылья_веры.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Крылья_веры.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNejr.png)

Comment: one advice do not use russian name, i think it is better to use Romanization of Russian.

Comment: So this could be a solution to the problem?

Comment: that was just an advice.most russians websites use the romanization of russian in their urls and in Django you can have a lot of trouble when dealing with foreign symbols sometimes.

Comment: Understood. I will correct. Thanks a lot for the advice!

Comment: Problem solved. It turned out that it was enough just to clear the browser cache. It's so simple! Thanks to all!